# Is it still atomic if the desired value of std::atomic<T>::compare_exchange_weak is return of a non-atomic operation?

Tags: c++, concurrency, atomic, race-condition, lock-free

Does **head.load()->next** break the atomicity here for the **std::atomic::compare_exchange_weak** used in **while(head && !head.compare_exchange_weak(ptr, head.load()->next));** ? I believe it should, but again it does not seem so in the output (which is below after the code sample). Or even, does this question make sense?

Another question: is **new_node->next = head.exchange(new_node);** an atomic operation? I mean, surely the std::atomic::exchange is atomic, but what about the assignment of the return value? (Let's assume that the variable *new_node* is accessed by other threads, would any thread be able to come in between the assignment of the return value?)

Here is the code sample (compiled with -std=c++17 flag):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <iomanip>
#include <array>
#include <future>
#include <mutex>
#include <exception>

static constexpr unsigned num_of_thread{ 100U };

struct Node{
    unsigned data;
    Node* next;

    Node() : data{0}, next{nullptr} {}
    Node(unsigned val) : data{val}, next{nullptr} {}
};

void test1() {
    std::atomic<Node*> head{ nullptr };
    std::cout << "Is lock-free?: " << std::boolalpha << head.is_lock_free() << std::endl;

    auto add_new_node = [&head](std::mutex& mut,
                                std::condition_variable& cond_var,
                                bool& guarantor,
                                unsigned i)
    {
        // Every thread creates its own unique node, so, no race condition here
        Node* new_node{ new Node{i} };
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck{ mut };
            cond_var.wait(lck, [&guarantor](){ return guarantor; });
            // All threads pile up here and wait for notification
            // (basically what std::barrier does)
        }

        // Ideally, all threads hit the below line at the same time.
        // Would there be a race condition here if new_node was a shared variable?
        // (Between the "exchange" atomic operation and the assignment of return value)
        new_node->next = head.exchange(new_node);
    };

    auto pop_a_node = [&head](std::mutex& mut,
                              std::condition_variable& cond_var,
                              bool& guarantor)
        {
        Node* ptr{ head };

        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck{ mut };
            cond_var.wait(lck, [&guarantor](){ return guarantor; });
            // All threads pile up here and wait for notification
            // (basically what std::barrier does)
        }

        // Do we break atomicity here by using head.load()->next?
        // Or even, does this question make sense? 
        while(head && !head.compare_exchange_weak(ptr, head.load()->next));

        // Using ptr from this point onwards is safe as it is local to every thread
        if(ptr) {
            unsigned retval{ ptr->data };
            delete ptr;
            
            // Protect concurrent access to std::cout (nothing else)
            // in order not to get a scrambled output
            mut.lock();
            std::cout << retval << ' ';
            mut.unlock();
        }
        else {
            mut.lock();
            std::cout << "* ";
            mut.unlock();
        }
    };

    // Half of the threads add, the other half pops nodes
    [&pop_a_node, &add_new_node]() {
        std::condition_variable cond_var{};
        bool guarantor{ false }; // Needed in order to prevent spurious wakeups
        std::mutex mut;

        std::array<std::thread, num_of_thread> threads{};
        for(unsigned i{}; i<num_of_thread; i++) {
            if(i%2U) {
                threads[i] = std::move(std::thread{add_new_node,
                                                   std::ref(mut),
                                                   std::ref(cond_var),
                                                   std::ref(guarantor),
                                                   i});
            }
            else {
                threads[i] = std::move(std::thread{pop_a_node,
                                                   std::ref(mut),
                                                   std::ref(cond_var),
                                                   std::ref(guarantor)});
            }
        }

        // Wake all threads up at the same time. This should allow
        // more race condition possibilities compared to
        // just starting new threads repeatedly 
        guarantor = true;
        cond_var.notify_all();

        for(unsigned i{}; i<num_of_thread; i++) {
            threads[i].join();
        }
    }();
}

int main() {
    test1();

    return 0;
}
```

And here is a sample output:
Is lock-free?: true

- 49 9 71 69 95 * * * 97 3 87 * 27 81 85 51 11 29 53 5 * 31 23 19 99 45 * 55 83 13 * * 75 25 33 77 73 61 93 91 35 57 67 79 63 65 47 41 17

(The *s are when a thread cannot pop an element due to meeting an empty list. I checked the missing elements are still in the list.)

Comment: The assignment to `new_node->next` doesn't need to be `atomic`; the code hasn't published a reference to `new_node` anywhere that other threads could be accessing it.  For now, the members of that object are private to this thread, so can safely be written.

Comment: But it would be a problem for example in case the `new_node` was a shared variable which is returned at the end of the function call. So, the exchange is atomic, but the assignment of return is not. Got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the while loop

```
while(head && !head.compare_exchange_weak(ptr, head.load()->next));
```

you have 3 distinct atomic ops which are sequenced in order, but the whole thing is not atomic, so other threads might come in and do things between them

- head (load head and check for null)
- head.load() (load head and then deref to get `next`)
- head.compare_exchange

The obvious issue is that if two threads do a 'pop' at the same time, you might have the second thread come in and do its stuff between step 1 and 2 for the first thread.  If there's only one thing on the stack at the time, then the first thread could pass the null check, and then get a nullptr on the second step (and likely crash dereferencing it).

Normally one would write this loop as

```
while((ptr = head.load()) && !head.compare_exchange_weak(ptr, ptr->next));
```

That is, you only do a single load of the head value in the loop and then use that local value.  This still has the classic [ABA race problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABA_problem) if a node can be popped, freed, realloced and repushed all while one thread is trying to pop.  That may or may not be a problem -- as long as the popping thread does not try to do anything with the node prior to completely popping it, it doesn't matter if it got switched out to a different node.  It's still a node that was pushed and hasn't been popped by anyone else.

---

You have a similar problem in your push primitive

```
new_node->next = head.exchange(new_node);
```

The store into `new_node->next` is not atomic with the exchange, so another thread might access it after the `head.exchange`, but before the store.  So that code should be<sup>1</sup>:

```
do { new_node->next = head.load(); } while (!head.compare_exchange_weak(new_node->next, new_node));
```

This ensures that the store happens *before* the atomic operation that publishes the newly pushed node.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>or `while ((new_node->next = head.load()), !head.compare_exchange_weak(new_node->next, new_node));` if you prefer that style</sub>

Comment: I wasn't sure about it but this is exactly what I would expect to happen! Your answer clarifies all. Thanks!

Comment: I believe you are missing `nullptr ` checks for the head in the second and third `while` loops.

Comment: The second loop checks for null.  The final loop (for the push) doesn't need a check as pushing on to an empty stack (when head is null) is fine.

Answer (score 1):

`head->compareExchangeWeak(x,y)` is a function call. As in any function call, the argument expressions, (`x`, and `y` in this case) are evaluated *before* the function is called.

You wrote `head.compare_exchange_weak(ptr, head.load()->next))`.

The *expressions,* `ptr` and `head.load()->next` both are evaluated *before* compareExchangeWeak is ever called. The actual *argments* that are passed in to the compare_exchange_weak function are just the two pointers--the expected, and the new. The call to `head.load()` is ancient history by the time that happens.

Does that answer your question?

Comment: This is a partial answer to this question but it points out the underlying dynamics that may cause a similar problem I was trying to understand; the node that the head pointer points to may be deallocated by another thread right before the arguments for the `compare_exchange_weak` call is prepared (after head pointer is checked for null), which causes UB when head.load()->next is fetched. Thanks for pointing out this dynamic, it helped me understand that this can happen.